# React.js displaying error messages next to belonging input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created an API login/register system with Django and React.js, I have my Back-End up and running, the registration system itself is fully functioning, what I need right now is a way to display response messages after the API call from React.js to Django. All the errors after API call are being stored as object in the state. So far I just displayed all the messages like this:

[image]

What I need now is a way to make them look like this:

[image]

So basically the error message itself JSX code is:

```
<small style={{color: '#ea0027',marginBottom: '0.5rem',fontWeight: 'bold',}}>
    <li style={{ listStyleType: 'circle' }}>{name} {error}</li>
</small>
```

And this is how I render the messages now:

```
 {Object.entries(this.state.errors).map(([name, error]) => (
     <small style={{color: '#ea0027',marginBottom: '0.5rem',fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
        <li style={{ listStyleType: 'circle' }}>{name} {error}</li>
     </small>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe somthing like this. i dont know how the data in this.state.error looks so maybe you can select it out of error like in this example

```
  {Object.entries(this.state.errors).map(([name, error]) => (
   return (
                <>
           <li style={{ listStyleType: "circle" }}>
            <RegisterInput
              type="text"
              invalid={true}
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              placeholder="Choose a username"
              autoComplete="new-username"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
              pattern="^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9._]{3,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[^_.].*[^_.]$"
            />
             {error.username}
          </li>
         <li style={{ listStyleType: "circle" }}>
            <RegisterInput
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              autoComplete="new-email"
              placeholder="Enter your email address"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
            />
            {error.email}
          </li>
          <li style={{ listStyleType: "circle" }}>
             <RegisterInput
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              placeholder="Password"
              autoComplete="new-password"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
            />
            {error.password}
          </li>
          <li style={{ listStyleType: "circle" }}>
            <RegisterInput
              type="password"
              name="re_password"
              value={this.state.re_password}
              placeholder="Confirm password"
              autoComplete="new-re-password"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
            />
            {error.re_password}
          </li>
         </>
       )
      ))}
```

Comment: @DziugitoBizox can you give the data in this.state.errors ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f3be8f2a63d6404e53e969e538372865 the object inside errors is in this format 
`{"email":["Enter a valid email address."],"username":["user with this username already exists."]}`

Comment: so to better understand the object in this.state.errors = {"email":["Enter a valid email address."],"username":["user with this username already exists."]}